# Better way to find if item exists in JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have and array which contains more then 10 000 values and somehow `lodash` method `includes` stopped working.

The example of array:

```
  ['888888111118888',
  '7771117717717771']
```

And my method (not working) but were working yesterday as well (with lower amount of values in array)

```
toFind = '7771117717717771'; // this is just for example
return _.includes(arr, toFind);
```

and no matter if the `toFind` is in array the method returns "false". Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

so this is what I have noticed now:

```
        console.log(data.memberList.members[0].steamID64[7]);
        toFind = data.memberList.members[0].steamID64[7];
        console.log(_.findIndex(data.memberList.members[0].steamID64, toFind));
```

and it responds with:

```
999999999999
-1
```

so how is this even possible?

Comment: It might be a typo but in your example the array contains strings and the `toFind` is a number.

Comment: like as I said before it is just an example, `toFind` is the exact same expression as object elements

Comment: If you bring examples, make sure they reflect what you have. You can't hand-wave over non-working code and expect that we know which mistakes are real and which ones are not. Make the example fail in *precisely* the same way that your current code does.

Comment: thanks, fixed all typos!

Comment: Anything wrong with Array.prototype.findIndex? It gives you back the index of the match, so you can just do that O(1) lookup. You can match on anything, e.g. findIndex ( x => return x.someval === 'whatever' ), which returns the index or -1 then you just do myArr [ theIndex ].

Comment: @TimConsolazio I'm not sure how to use it but Ive tried many methods to find index by value and it returns -1 for me.

Comment: @TimConsolazio `.findIndex()` is O(n) - or did you mean something different?

Comment: The lookup with the found index is O(1).

Comment: True, but that's true for `.includes()` as well. To actually *find* an array element you have O(n) complexity, no matter what method you use.

Comment: The edited code in the question now returns true for me. It originally returned false when `toFind` was a number. So...are you sure you're using `_.includes()` correctly, as per the lodash documentation, for your actual use case? Lodash is going to apply specific types of equality comparisons.

Comment: Yes Tomalak. I didn't state the O of findIndex. I said the lookup was O(1), and that's correct.

Comment: edited the question with more details

Comment: To address the new example...Have you looked at the documentation for `_.findIndex`? I think you're supposed to supply a predicate i.e. `_.findIndex(data.memberList.members[0].steamID64, i => i === toFind)`, like the ES6 Array.prototype.find method.

Answer (score 0):

Example of Array.prototype.findIndex:

```
let arr = [ "123", "456" ];
let index = arr.findIndex ( x => { return x === "123" } );
```

This will return 0 (the first index of "123"). If you have objects:

```
let arr = [ { val : "123" }, { val : "456" } ];
let index = arr.findIndex ( x => { return x.val === "123" } );
```

And so on. If you get -1, either your matcher is wrong, or it's not in the array.

I have tremendous respect for lodash, but as we get increasing native capability such as maps, sets, along with other functional higher order capabilities (filter, map, reduce, findIndex, etc), I've found my use of it diminishing.

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.find

```
let result = arr.find(r => r ==='7771117717717771');
```

If result is defined then it exists in the array. If you are looking for an operation that runs faster than O(n) time, you should look into alternative data structures such as maps or trees

Comment: that returns "7771117717717771" is not a function.

Comment: that returns undefined as well